# Connection.release() does not release the connections to the pool and causing memory leak in node-oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, memory-leaks, node-oracledb

I have a Node js application which connects to the oracle DB. Connection.release doesnt release the connection back to the pool, which is causing the memory leak and the program gets crashed.

```
let connection = await getConnection(poolconfiguration); //gets connection from pool
let result = await executequery(connection, query); //executes query and returns result
connection.release(); //releases the connection to the pool
return result;  //returns the result to the called function
```

Do we need to do any cleanup for the results we get from each incoming requests?

Comment: Agree with Christopher re `await`. But it also looks like a design problem: if you want `await` function you should wrap into separate `async` function which gets connection, executes an input query, releases the connection back to the pool and returns its results, and you need to call this separate function with `await`

Comment: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/resultset1.js

Comment: Yep, good design is important.  If a few consecutive statements are being executed then it would be even better to get the connection once, execute all the statements, and then close the connection (aka release it back to the pool).

Answer (score 0):

Please post a complete script and show what functions like `executequery` do.  At a guess from the snippet, you should use `await`, e.g. `await connection.close()`

The `connection.release()` function is an alias for `connection.close()`, but is deprecated - the doc says it will be removed in a future version.

Check all the node-oracledb [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) for good practices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's inside your variable `poolConfiguration` since you are not sharing that info, but it seems you should do:

```
await connection.close({drop: true});
```

So instead of `release()`

Otherwise the connection remains.

> If drop is true, the connection will be completely dropped from the
> connection pool

[node-oracledb Documentation on connection.close()](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#connection.close)